# Is $R[X_1,X_2,\cdots]/\langle X_1,X_2,\cdots\rangle$ finitely presented?

Tags: commutative-algebra

This is exercise 5.29 from *A Term of Commutative Algebra* by A. Altman & S. Kleiman.
A digital version may be found [here](https://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/arithmetic_geometry/teaching/exercises/Altman_-Kleiman---A-term-of-commutative-algebra-_2017_.pdf).
The statement of the exercise is the following.

> Let $R$ be a ring, $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ infinitely many variables.
> Set $P:=R[X_1,X_2,\cdots]$ and $M:=P/\langle X_1,X_2,\cdots\rangle$.
> Is $M$ finitely presented?
> Explain.

The solution attached at the end of the book is the following.

> No, otherwise by (5.18), the ideal $\langle X_1, X2, \cdots\rangle$ would be generated
> by some $f_1,\cdots,f_n\in P$, so also by $X_1,\cdots,X_m$ for some $m$, but plainly it isn’t.

The (5.18) in the proof above refers to the following.

> Let $R$ be a ring, and $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow R^n \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ an exact
> sequence. Prove $M$ is finitely presented if and only if $L$ is finitely generated.

However, I have the following questions:

1. By *$M$ finitely presented*, does the author mean finitely presented as a module over $R$?
2. By referring to (5.18), the author seems to be considering the following exact sequence:
   $$0\rightarrow \langle X_1,X_2,\cdots\rangle \rightarrow R[X_1,X_2,\cdots] \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0.$$
   However, $R[X_1,X_2,\cdots]$ does not have the form $R^n$ required by (5.18).
3. Isn't $M\cong R$ and therefore finitely presented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No: over $P$.
2. $P=P^1$.
3. Not as a $P$-module.